# NatTable - copy & paste cell data with line separator inside cell

Tags: nattable, nebula

My copy & paste works well for Nattables. Problem comes, if some cell contains line separator. When I paste data, line separator is taken as a row separator and structure of my table is destructed.

In `CopyDataToClipboardCommand.class`:

```
public CopyDataToClipboardCommand(String cellDelimeter,
        String rowDelimeter, IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
    this.cellDelimeter = cellDelimeter;
    this.rowDelimeter = rowDelimeter;
    this.configRegistry = configRegistry;
}
```

cellDelimeter is set to `\t` and rowDelimeter is set to `\r\n`.

Inside problematic cells is new line set with `\n`. Any idea about this?

Comment: where do you paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about pasting to Excel for example, then the issue is not in NatTable, it is in Excel. Excel treats a new line character as a row delimiter. The configuration in `CopyDataToClipboardCommand` is used to add that character for ADDING a new row.

If you want to be able to copy cell content that contains new line characters and paste it in Excel, you probably need to override `CopyDataCommandHandler#internalDoCommand()` and use a custom serializer that replaces the new line characters in the cell to something Excel can handle. Actually I don't know what character is treated as a line separater inside a cell in Excel. I probably would replace it with a simple space then.

Comment: You are right. Java knows only line separator. Excel does use combination `Alt+Enter` to achieve new row inside cell. there is nothing similar in Java.

Comment: how to use custom serializer? I can override for example style in tables or register CopyDataCommandHandler, but not serializer. @Dirk Fauth